# A is a 5x5 matrix such that the fifth row is a linear combination of the first 2 rows. **Which of the following is true?**

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-analysis

A is a 5x5 matrix such that the fifth row is a linear combination of the first 2 rows. **Which of the following is true?**

(1) 5th column of A is a linear combination of the first 2 columns

(2) Columns of A form a basis for $\mathbb{R^5}$

(3) Columns of A form a linearly dependent set.

(4) det(A) = $ 0$

**Only (3), (4) is true.** (4) is true because when A is reduced to REF, the last row is a zero row, determinant of REF is $0$. (3) is true as when A is reduced to REF, the last column is a non-pivot column, so the the fifth column vector will be a redundant vector. Please correct me if I am wrong, thank you. Does the linear dependency of the rows indicate anything about the linear dependency of the columns?

Comment: I am sure that you can find a counterexample for $(2)$. A little playing around will get you a counter example for $(1)$ as well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon For (1) and (2) , am I correct in saying that any of the columns can be expressed as linear combination of the other 4 column vectors, it doesn't necessarily have to be the fifth column vector that is redundant?

Comment: You need to give an example that 2 is not true, by finding a matrix such that the last row is a combination of first and second, but this need not be true for the columns

Comment: True, any column is a linear combination of the remaining 4 columns, which negates (2), but doesn't tell you anything about (1).